# Verification in Big O notation

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, asymptotics

Suppose $f(x)$ is sum of the series whose terms are $f_n(x)$ and series converging uniformly and absolutely. It’s also given that $|f_n(x)|=O(g(x) a_n)$ as $n$ tends to infinity and series with terms $a_n$ also converges. Then can we conclude that $f(x)=O(g(x))$ as x tends to infinity?

My guess: If $f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)$ and $|f_n(x)|=O(g(x) a_n)$ then after certain $n$ we have $f_n$ is bounded by $g(x)a_n$ and since  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ converges $g(x)$ will come out of series and give  $f(x)=O(g(x)) $ as x tends to infinity.
Please verify whether this argument is correct.

Comment: I guess $$|f_n(x)|=O(g(x) a_n)\text{ as } n \to \infty$$ means for each fixed $x$ we have that estimate, and the constants may vary with $x$ in an arbitrary manner??  Then the conclusion $$f(x) = O(g(x))\text{ as }n\to \infty$$ is meaningless.  Do you want a different "as" clause for this $O$ ??  Please clarify the statement.

Comment: I want $f(x)=O(g(x)) $ as x tends to infinity given $|f_n(x)|=O(g(x)a_n) $ as n tends to infinity. And for each fixed x we have that estimate.

Comment: Well, fix the question to show what these $O$ statements mean.

Comment: Yes fixed that! Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

If the O-constant depends on neither $x$ nor $n$ then the following proof works (this is basically what you get after elaborating your guess):

It is known that there exists $K_1>0$ such that
$$
|f_n(x)|\le K_1g(x)a_n
$$

This means if we set $K_2=K_1\sum_na_n$ then

$$
\sum_n|f_n(x)|\le K_2g(x)
$$

Now, by triangle inequality we get

$$
|f(x)|=\left|\sum_nf_n(x)\right|\le\sum_n|f_n(x)|
$$

Therefore, we see that $f(x)=\mathcal O(g(x))$.